# How to scale a TikZ matrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, scale

I have the following matrix:

[image]

which is obtained from the following code:

```
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}


%opening
\title{}
\author{}


\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixenv/.style={decoration={brace},every left delimiter/.style={xshift=8pt},every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-8pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]},inner sep=1pt,outer sep=1.5pt,column sep=8pt,row sep=8pt,nodes={minimum width=20pt,minimum height=10pt,anchor=center,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixbrace/.style={decorate,thick}}

\newcommand*\mymatrixbraceright[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.west|-#1-#3-1.south west) -- node[left=2pt] {#4} (#1.west|-#1-#2-1.north west);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbraceleft[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.east|-#1-#2-1.north east) -- node[right=2pt] {#4} (#1.east|-#1-#2-1.south east);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbracetop[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.north-|#1-1-#2.north west) -- node[above=2pt] {#4} (#1.north-|#1-1-#3.north east);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbracebottom[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.south-|#1-1-#2.north east) -- node[below=2pt] {#4} (#1.south-|#1-1-#3.north west);
}


\tikzset{style green/.style={
    set fill color=green!50!lime!60,draw opacity=0.4,
    set border color=green!50!lime!60,fill opacity=0.1,
  },
  style cyan/.style={
    set fill color=cyan!90!blue!60, draw opacity=0.4,
    set border color=blue!70!cyan!30,fill opacity=0.1,
  },
  style orange/.style={
    set fill color=orange!90, draw opacity=0.8,
    set border color=orange!90, fill opacity=0.3,
  },
  style brown/.style={
    set fill color=brown!70!orange!40, draw opacity=0.4,
    set border color=brown, fill opacity=0.3,
  },
  style purple/.style={
    set fill color=violet!90!pink!20, draw opacity=0.5,
    set border color=violet, fill opacity=0.3,    
  },
  kwad/.style={
    above left offset={-0.1,0.23},
    below right offset={0.10,-0.36},
    #1
  },
  pion/.style={
    above left offset={-0.07,0.2},
    below right offset={0.07,-0.32},
    #1
  },
  poz/.style={
    above left offset={-0.03,0.18},
    below right offset={0.03,-0.3},
    #1
  }
}

\[
%    \mathbf{X} = 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={-0.5ex},mymatrixenv]
        \matrix [mymatrix,inner sep=4pt] (m)  
        {
    \tikzmarkin[kwad=style green]{Prime} v_{1,1}  &  v_{1,2} & \tikzmarkin[pion=style purple]{VL} v_{1,3}   &  \textcolor{white}{v_{1,4}}   &  &  \textcolor{white}{v_{1,6}} \\
    v_{2,1}  & v_{2,2} & v_{2,3} & & &   \\
    \tikzmarkin[poz=style brown]{HL} v_{3,1}  & v_{3,2} & \tikzmarkin[kwad=style orange]{Mix} v_{3,3} \tikzmarkend{Prime} &\tikzmarkin[pion=style purple]{VR} v_{3,4}  \tikzmarkend{HL} & &   \\
    \textcolor{white}{v_{4,1}}    & & \tikzmarkin[poz=style brown]{HR} v_{4,3} \tikzmarkend{VL}& \tikzmarkin[kwad=style cyan]{Bis} v_{4,4} \tikzmarkend{Mix} & v_{4,5}  & v_{4,6} \tikzmarkend{HR}   \\
    & & & v_{5,4} & v_{5,5} & v_{5,6}   \\
    \textcolor{white}{v_{6,1}}  & &  & v_{6,4}  \tikzmarkend{VR} & v_{6,5} & v_{6,6} \tikzmarkend{Bis}  \\    
    };

        % Braces     
        \mymatrixbraceright{1}{3}{$B'$}
        \mymatrixbraceright{4}{6}{$B''$}
        \mymatrixbracetop{1}{3}{$C'$}
        \mymatrixbracetop{4}{6}{$C''$}
        \mymatrixbracebottom{3}{3}{$F'$}
        \mymatrixbracebottom{4}{4}{$F''$}
        \mymatrixbraceleft{3}{3}{$E'$}
        \mymatrixbraceleft{4}{4}{$E''$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
```

I was trying to change:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={-0.5ex},mymatrixenv]
```

to

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,baseline={-0.5ex},mymatrixenv]
```

but without effect.

I also tried this when I import the picture to another document:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\scalebox{2}{
\input{color_matrix3.tikz}
}
\end{figure}
```

the output was indeed bigger but not centered and latex gave a lot of errors concerning math equations

Comment: `\usepackage{adjustbox} ... \adjustbox{scale=2,center}{...}` or `\begin{adjustbox}{scale=2,center}` ... `\end{adjustbox}`. Instead of `scale=2` maybe a `width=\textwidth` or some other length is more suitable.

Comment: For the centering see [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth)

Comment: Your code is not compileable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me start by providing a compilable version of your code. Apart from obvious additions I also guessed some styles from the context, and as any guess my guesses may be wrong. In any case, this is what I got.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}


%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixenv/.style={decoration={brace},every left delimiter/.style={xshift=8pt},every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-8pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]},inner sep=1pt,outer sep=1.5pt,column sep=8pt,row sep=8pt,nodes={minimum width=20pt,minimum height=10pt,anchor=center,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixbrace/.style={decorate,thick}}

\newcommand*\mymatrixbraceright[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.west|-#1-#3-1.south west) -- node[left=2pt] {#4} (#1.west|-#1-#2-1.north west);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbraceleft[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.east|-#1-#2-1.north east) -- node[right=2pt] {#4} (#1.east|-#1-#2-1.south east);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbracetop[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.north-|#1-1-#2.north west) -- node[above=2pt] {#4} (#1.north-|#1-1-#3.north east);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbracebottom[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.south-|#1-1-#2.north east) -- node[below=2pt] {#4} (#1.south-|#1-1-#3.north west);
}


\tikzset{style green/.style={
    set fill color=green!50!lime!60,draw opacity=0.4,
    set border color=green!50!lime!60,fill opacity=0.1,
  },
  style cyan/.style={
    set fill color=cyan!90!blue!60, draw opacity=0.4,
    set border color=blue!70!cyan!30,fill opacity=0.1,
  },
  style orange/.style={
    set fill color=orange!90, draw opacity=0.8,
    set border color=orange!90, fill opacity=0.3,
  },
  style brown/.style={
    set fill color=brown!70!orange!40, draw opacity=0.4,
    set border color=brown, fill opacity=0.3,
  },
  style purple/.style={
    set fill color=violet!90!pink!20, draw opacity=0.5,
    set border color=violet, fill opacity=0.3,    
  },
  kwad/.style={
    above left offset={-0.1,0.23},
    below right offset={0.10,-0.36},
    #1
  },
  pion/.style={
    above left offset={-0.07,0.2},
    below right offset={0.07,-0.32},
    #1
  },
  poz/.style={
    above left offset={-0.03,0.18},
    below right offset={0.03,-0.3},
    #1
  },set fill color/.code={\pgfkeysalso{fill=#1}},
  set border color/.style={draw=#1}
}

\[
%    \mathbf{X} = 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={-0.5ex},mymatrixenv]
        \matrix [mymatrix,inner sep=4pt] (m)  
        {
    \tikzmarkin[kwad=style green]{Prime} v_{1,1}  &  v_{1,2} & \tikzmarkin[pion=style purple]{VL} v_{1,3}   &  \textcolor{white}{v_{1,4}}   &  &  \textcolor{white}{v_{1,6}} \\
    v_{2,1}  & v_{2,2} & v_{2,3} & & &   \\
    \tikzmarkin[poz=style brown]{HL} v_{3,1}  & v_{3,2} & \tikzmarkin[kwad=style orange]{Mix} v_{3,3} \tikzmarkend{Prime} &\tikzmarkin[pion=style purple]{VR} v_{3,4}  \tikzmarkend{HL} & &   \\
    \textcolor{white}{v_{4,1}}    & & \tikzmarkin[poz=style brown]{HR} v_{4,3} \tikzmarkend{VL}& \tikzmarkin[kwad=style cyan]{Bis} v_{4,4} \tikzmarkend{Mix} & v_{4,5}  & v_{4,6} \tikzmarkend{HR}   \\
    & & & v_{5,4} & v_{5,5} & v_{5,6}   \\
    \textcolor{white}{v_{6,1}}  & &  & v_{6,4}  \tikzmarkend{VR} & v_{6,5} & v_{6,6} \tikzmarkend{Bis}  \\    
    };

        % Braces     
        \mymatrixbraceright{1}{3}{$B'$}
        \mymatrixbraceright{4}{6}{$B''$}
        \mymatrixbracetop{1}{3}{$C'$}
        \mymatrixbracetop{4}{6}{$C''$}
        \mymatrixbracebottom{3}{3}{$F'$}
        \mymatrixbracebottom{4}{4}{$F''$}
        \mymatrixbraceleft{3}{3}{$E'$}
        \mymatrixbraceleft{4}{4}{$E''$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, this does produce a reasonable result, but entirely by accident IMHO. You are nesting `tikzpictures`. If you were to add something like `scale=2`, the result will be completely off since some things will be transformed twice. One option to achieve the scaling is to employ `adjustbox`, as [pointed out by Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer). I leave it to you or Martin Scharrer to spell this out even more explicitly.

I recommend going another way in which you do not have to nest `tikzpicture`s. This way is IMHO also much more elegant as it does not require any manual adjustments as in the `pion` style etc. Your matrix is already a matrix of nodes, and there is no need to resort to `hf-tikz`. You can just use `fit` instead.  Of course, you *can* shift the contours and adjust their height by playing with `xshift`, `yshift`, `inner xsep` and `inner ysep`. (I did not clean up your code further e.g. by replacing the `\textcolor{white}{...}` by their `tikz` counterparts.) This thing can be scaled just by setting `\myscale` to the desired value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,fit,backgrounds}


%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myscale}{2}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixenv/.style={decoration={brace},every left delimiter/.style={xshift=8pt},every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-8pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells,
left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]},inner sep=1pt,outer sep=1.5pt,
column sep=8pt,row sep=8pt,nodes={minimum width=20pt,minimum height=10pt,
anchor=center,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,scale=\myscale,transform shape}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixbrace/.style={decorate,thick}}

\newcommand*\mymatrixbraceright[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.west|-#1-#3-1.south west) -- node[left=2pt] {#4} (#1.west|-#1-#2-1.north west);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbraceleft[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.east|-#1-#2-1.north east) -- node[right=2pt] {#4} (#1.east|-#1-#2-1.south east);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbracetop[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.north-|#1-1-#2.north west) -- node[above=2pt] {#4} (#1.north-|#1-1-#3.north east);
}
\newcommand*\mymatrixbracebottom[4][m]{
    \draw[mymatrixbrace] (#1.south-|#1-1-#2.north east) -- node[below=2pt] {#4} (#1.south-|#1-1-#3.north west);
}


\tikzset{greenish/.style={
    fill=green!50!lime!60,draw opacity=0.4,
    draw=green!50!lime!60,fill opacity=0.1,
  },
  cyanish/.style={
    fill=cyan!90!blue!60, draw opacity=0.4,
    draw=blue!70!cyan!30,fill opacity=0.1,
  },
  orangeish/.style={
    fill=orange!90, draw opacity=0.8,
    draw=orange!90, fill opacity=0.3,
  },
  brownish/.style={
    fill=brown!70!orange!40, draw opacity=0.4,
    draw=brown, fill opacity=0.3,
  },
  purpleish/.style={
    fill=violet!90!pink!20, draw opacity=0.5,
    draw=violet, fill opacity=0.3,    
  }}


\[
%    \mathbf{X} = 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={-0.5ex},mymatrixenv]
        \matrix [mymatrix,inner sep=4pt] (m)  
        {
    v_{1,1}  &  v_{1,2} & v_{1,3}   &  \textcolor{white}{v_{1,4}}   &  &  \textcolor{white}{v_{1,6}} \\
    v_{2,1}  & v_{2,2} & v_{2,3} & & &   \\
    v_{3,1}  & v_{3,2} &  v_{3,3} & v_{3,4} & &   \\
    \textcolor{white}{v_{4,1}}    & &  v_{4,3} &  v_{4,4}  & v_{4,5}  & v_{4,6}   \\
    & & & v_{5,4} & v_{5,5} & v_{5,6}   \\
    \textcolor{white}{v_{6,1}}  & &  & v_{6,4}  & v_{6,5} & v_{6,6}   \\    
    };

    \begin{scope}[on background layer,rounded corners]
     \node [fit=(m-1-1) (m-3-3),greenish,inner xsep=1.5pt,inner ysep=2.5pt]{};
     \node [fit=(m-1-3) (m-4-3),purpleish,inner xsep=0.5pt,inner ysep=3.5pt]{};
     \node [fit=(m-3-1) (m-3-4),brownish,inner xsep=0.5pt,inner ysep=1.5pt]{};
     \node [fit=(m-3-3) (m-4-4),orangeish]{};
     \node [fit=(m-3-4) (m-6-5),purpleish,inner xsep=0.5pt,inner ysep=3.5pt,yshift=1pt]{};
     \node [fit=(m-4-3) (m-4-6),brownish]{};
     \node [fit=(m-4-4) (m-6-6),cyanish,inner xsep=1.5pt,inner ysep=0.5pt,xshift=-1pt]{};
    \end{scope}

        % Braces     
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={scale=\myscale,transform
    shape},very thick]
        \mymatrixbraceright{1}{3}{$B'$}
        \mymatrixbraceright{4}{6}{$B''$}
        \mymatrixbracetop{1}{3}{$C'$}
        \mymatrixbracetop{4}{6}{$C''$}
        \mymatrixbracebottom{3}{3}{$F'$}
        \mymatrixbracebottom{4}{4}{$F''$}
        \mymatrixbraceleft{3}{3}{$E'$}
        \mymatrixbraceleft{4}{4}{$E''$}
    \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! Do you know how to make borders of colorful regions ticker (as on my picture)?

Comment: @FilipParker Sure. Just replace `\begin{scope}[on background layer,rounded corners]` by `\begin{scope}[on background layer,rounded corners,every node/.append style={line width=2pt}]`.

Comment: I am trying to understand your code. Is it true that the macro named ``\mymatrixbraceright`` places braces on the left and ``\mymatrixbraceleft`` places braces on the right???