# \newgeometry \restoregeometry makes setup for page only?

Tags: graphics, geometry

I have pictures that require the use of the full-page width, with having less margin on both the left and right sides. Therefore, I tried with `\newgeometry` to set the margins at 1cm on both sides, though this brings me the following issue:

When directly after the picture I restore the geometry to its original content with  `\restoregeometry`, the rest of the page is just moved to the next separate page. Also, the picture is not put on the same page as it was intended (below some text, while using `[!h]` and space is available).

How is this possible, and more important, how can I fix it?

Comment: You don't need to change the geometry to insert graphics which are wider than  \linewidth. Something like `\centering\makebox[\linewidth]{graphic}` should work.

Comment: [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/134144)  might be interesting.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be helpful if you could provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) in order to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions, I have succesfully implemented the \makebox method from leandriis