# Position Figure in the Center

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I want to put figure in the document so that it is positioned in the center but its margin goes beyond linewidth. For that I am using the following command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.3\linewidth]{norm.png}
\caption{A Normal Dist}
\label{fig: borm}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The picture that I am using is attached to this post and can be seen below.

[image]

If I put the code in this way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{norm.png}
\caption{A Normal Dist}
\label{fig: borm}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Then the picture is set to the center nicely, but i want it to extend over the linewidth both to the left and to the right equally. If I use the code I copied previously then the picture extend indeed, but it extends only to the right not to the left.

Can anybody help me fix the issue.

I have read documentation for graphics, graphicx but i could not find it out there.

Comment: Check this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16584/120578 ... Possibly duplicate. By the way, try to replace your figures with `example-image-a` and `-b` in your MWE (if no special reason to use a specific image) in order to be easier for a test from the people that are trying to help.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [Center figure that is wider than `\textwidth`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582)

Comment: @barbarabeeton ... I just linked the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will check and if it is duplicate I will delete my post immediately. Thanks.

Comment: @G.T. ... Deleting a post is not a really recommended move... It is better to let us mark it as a duplicate ... Somebody could find the solution after finding your post.