# Centering a pair of overfull PDFs

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, pdf, input, layout

I'm trying to get to the bottom of how to position and center things.

Here I've placed two very large PDFs side-by-side. I scaled them down to  the current size and tried to center them:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\centering
\begin{figure}
%
\centering
  \begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.45\textwidth}%
    \begin{center}
      {\includegraphics[scale=0.085]{diagrams/pdf/square.pdf}} 
    \end{center}
  \caption{I sit hard up against the left margin}
  \end{minipage}\hfill{}%
%
  \begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.45\textwidth}%
    \begin{center}
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.085]{diagrams/pdf/square.pdf}}
    \end{center}
  \caption{I hang over the edge of the right margin}
  \end{minipage}\hfill{}%
%
\end{figure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

It kind of works, but it only hangs over the right margin, so it's not truly centered. If I scale them down even further, there's a point where it's no longer a problem, but say it's impractical to make them any smaller than `0.085`%, and you just want it to look more like this:

[image]

Notice how the page is perfectly symmetrical, with respect to the positions of the two figures and the excess is distributed evenly between the margins?

How can I achieve this? I thought my use of `minipage` would sort this out, but I guess not.

Comment: Not a very good solution but you could get what you want by using the `\hspace` command. You can pass negative lengths to it. So if you are overlapping the right margin by let's say 2cm, you could put a `\hspace{-1cm}` before including the left image (or the minipage if you're using one). Let's hope there exists a better solution to this though...

Comment: @Raven Yes, thanks for mentioning it. I was going to but I forgot what the command was. I agree. It's difficult to know exactly how big the overlap is. With a bit of trial and error you can get pretty close, but if you have to do it several times, it gets frustrating fast. Also the captions become offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way with the usage of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16584/120578).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\centering
\begin{figure}
%
\hspace{-0.025\textwidth}\makebox[1.05\textwidth][c]{
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t,outer sep=0]{0.45\textwidth}%
    \begin{center}
      {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}} 
    \end{center}
  \caption{I sit hard up against the left margin}
  \end{minipage}\hfill%
%
  \begin{minipage}[t,outer sep=0]{0.45\textwidth}%
    \begin{center}
    {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
    \end{center}
  \caption{I hang over the edge of the right margin}
  \end{minipage}}%
%
\end{figure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

PS1: If `\makebox` command creates a box of `1.05\textwidth` the `0.05\textwidth` will be added after the text width ... So reduce it by half with `\hspace{-0.025\textwidth}`

PS2: use the appropriate width for the minipages, but take care of the outer sep in case you will use the whole width of the `\makebox` command.

**Edit: Better way:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\centering
\begin{figure}
%
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t,outer sep=0]{0.525\textwidth}%
    \begin{center}
      {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}} 
    \end{center}
  \caption{I sit hard up against the left margin}
  \end{minipage}\hspace{0.5cm}%
%
  \begin{minipage}[t,outer sep=0]{0.525\textwidth}%
    \begin{center}
    {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
    \end{center}
  \caption{I hang over the edge of the right margin}
  \end{minipage}}%
%
\end{figure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can makebox be used _instead of_ minipage? Is it redundant in this case? Feels like we're playing with Russian nesting dolls.

Comment: `\makebox` is used here for the whole width to be used and this is the idea ... You could use any code that adds side by side the images ... I just used your way, but you can use any way available for side by side figures.

Comment: Strange, I just tried your code and it didn't work for me the way you picture it. Actually it stays the same.

Comment: You did something wrong in the replacement of the figure/pdf dimensions. Or didn't copy-pasted everything needed ... You may edit your post with this failed example to find easier help. Try the second way too (it is better)

Comment: I see, you have have replaced the `scale` with `width`. Was that intentional? That 
 might have been it. Actually I only tried the second way I think.

Comment: @tjt263 ... The second way was added after your failure due to widths ... So, possibly you initially used the first way that was not so clever (since a `\parbox` of text width is enough.)