# Single page with huge figure

Tags: floats, formatting, geometry, amsart

I'm writing a paper and I want to insert a figure that should occupy a whole page. Moreover, the figure has small details, so I want to reduce the margins in that page. On the other pages I'd like to use amsart margin settings.  I reproduce my attempt below. The problem with that implementation is that the page is not "floating", so there is a big empty area in the preceding page.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letter]{amsart}
\usepackage[marginratio=1:1,height=584pt,width=360pt,tmargin=117pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\begin{document}
\title{A note}
\author{me}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
See Figure~\ref{fig.main}.
\newgeometry{right=5mm, left=5mm} 
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{main_figure.pdf}
\caption{A huge figure.}\label{fig.main}
\end{figure}
\restoregeometry
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you only have to reduce the left and right margin to make the image fit into the page, you might want to take a look at adjustwidth. The solutions presented in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/134144 might also be useful.

Comment: I wouldn't try to change the page size with the `geometry` package.  Instead, I'd leave the figure floating, with `\begin{figure}[p]`.  I'd create a new dimension, say `\mydimen`, and set its size to `\textwidth` plus 10mm (the amount you've specified in your example with `\newgeometry`). Then in the figure, I'd insert the graphic with adjustments on the left and right: `\noindent\hspace*{-5mm}\includegraphics{width=\mydimen]{...}\hspace{-5mm}` The negative `\hspace`s should allow the graphic to overflow the width equally on each side without triggering an overfull hbox message.  (Not tested.)

Answer (score 1):

See if the next solution is what you expect:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letter]{amsart}
\usepackage[marginratio=1:1,
            height=584pt,
            width=360pt,
            tmargin=117pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{A note}
\author{me}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
See Figure~\ref{fig.main}.
    \begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-\marginparwidth}{-\marginparwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.93\textheight]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{A huge figure.}\label{fig.main}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)