# How do I fit the figures in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

How do we put figures in the center?
I use `\centering` but my figure is not fitted  in  the text
Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), thanks.

Comment: Although I can't look into a crystal ball right know i suggest you to look into the `adjustbox` package documentation.

Comment: it can not centre if it is too wide, use something like `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{yourimage}`

Comment: Possibly https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth is of interest, but consider if David's suggestion is better.