# Moving images on page with finer detail

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I have a few images that are very wide but not tall (bars of music). I'd like them to appear centered on the page, but the default \centering wants to line up the left part of the image with the left part of the text, meaning the right side of the image runs off the page. How can I force the image toward the left?

Right now it the source looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.35]{Figures/pictures/majmin7 chord.png}
    \caption{Major/Minor 7th Chord}
    \label{fig:majmin}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/134144)

Comment: perfect, thank you so much! wasn't sure what to search for.