# Align figure and/or table to the left before the page margin

Tags: tables, floats, align

I don't know the proper words to explain my question, but I want to align figures and tables more to the left. I use a two-column template and my figure and table are to large. So I want to align them more to the left in the left column. So they will be more to the left compared to where the text starts, like in my example below. Text is just the regular text and I want my image (and table) to be aligned more to the left.

[image: example of what I want]

Comment: The `adjustwidth` environment from the `changepage` package might be interesting. See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154766/134144

Comment: From your image I guess, you actually want to center an image that is wider than the textwidth with respect to the text, while allowing it to overflow into both margins.  Is that correct?

Comment: You also mention a `twocolumn` layout. Is your image wider than the width of one column or wider than both columns combined? Do you use `figure`or `figure*`?

Comment: Yes the image wider than the line width of one column, I use figure not figure*. I would like to adjust the placement like align -1cm (1cm to the left before the start of the line)

Comment: `\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{0pt}` might then be of interest.

Comment: Thank you, together with `\usepackage{changepage}` it works! {0pt} is the right margin right? Is there a reason why you used 0pt instead of 0cm? They both do the same, I think, my need for structure wants to keep both units the same.

Comment: There was no particular reason for using `0pt` rather than `0cm`. Just go with `0cm`.