# Increase the textwidth for figures in latex

Tags: floats, subfloats, textwidth

I want to make my subfigures bigger and keep them on the same line. Is there any way to increase the textwidth for the figure? Or are there any other ways to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
         \centering
         \caption{Annual Return}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{return.png}
     \end{subfigure}
     
     \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
         \centering
         \caption{Annual Volatility}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{volatility.png}
     \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/134144) could be interesting.

Comment: @leandriis, I must have misunderstood the question. If I compile the code above, the pictures are placed in two rows, when I thought OP wanted them in two columns.

Comment: @phil-elkabat: To be honest, I am not sure if I understood the question correctly. Let's wait for a clarification of the desired output from the OP.

Comment: The `\centering` instructions inside the `subfigure` environments are redundant.

Comment: The reason why the subfigures aren't placed on the same line is that you've inserted an all-blank line between them; the all-blank line acts to instruct LaTeX to insert a line break.

Answer (score 1):

Your example (even though not compilable, see [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/220875)) came pretty close:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{left image}
        \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{right image}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{There are two subfigures inside a figure environment}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The code above will yield the following output:

[image: subfigures]

Comment: +1. The comment character after the second instance of `\end{subfigure}` is not essential. However, just in case the OP chooses the widths of the two `subfigure` environments to something like `0.495\textwidth`, it's essential to use a `%` character immediately after the first instance of `\end{subfigure}`.

Comment: @Mico, you really have eyes like a hawk! Thank you, edit has been made.