# Move table to fit page

Tags: tables, margins

I know there are several similar thready, but I couldn't really find an answer...
I have a table that I simply can't fit on my page. I'm a beginner with Latex and almost giving up again... This is my header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{my_images/}}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\def\code#1{\texttt{#1}}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

 
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents


\listoffigures
\let\LaTeXStandardClearpage\clearpage
\let\clearpage\relax  % Do nothing when a \clearpage command appears 
\listoftables
\let\clearpage\LaTeXStandardClearpage % Return to the old definition


\input{01_introduction.tex}
\let\LaTeXStandardClearpage\clearpage
\let\clearpage\relax  % Do nothing when a \clearpage command appears 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{4}
\input{02_data_methods.tex}
\let\clearpage\LaTeXStandardClearpage % Return to the old definition
\input{03_results.tex}
\input{04_discussion.tex}
\input{05_conclusion.tex}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

And in the 2nd input I have this table:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(25)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(75)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
sqft\_living & 2,000 & 2,156.307 & 958.696 & 440 & 1,460 & 2,640 & 9,640 \\ 
view & 2,000 & 0.373 & 1.026 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\ 
condition & 2,000 & 3.417 & 0.654 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
grade & 2,000 & 7.748 & 1.200 & 4 & 7 & 8 & 13 \\ 
yr\_built & 1,800 & 1,973.880 & 28.719 & 1,900.000 & 1,954.000 & 2,000.000 & 2,014.000 \\ 
yr\_renovated & 2,000 & 118.719 & 472.126 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2,015 \\ 
sqft\_living15 & 2,000 & 2,033.584 & 705.835 & 460 & 1,500 & 2,450 & 5,030 \\ 
price\_per\_sqft & 2,000 & 269.090 & 118.534 & 87.588 & 184.960 & 320.706 & 800.000 \\ 
lot\_to\_living & 2,000 & 7.154 & 15.580 & 0.544 & 2.403 & 6.488 & 281.229 \\ 
basement\_percent & 2,000 & 0.127 & 0.172 & 0 & 0 & 0.3 & 1 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Which produces this ouput:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to move it a little to the left?

Comment: Instead of moving the table into the left margin, you could reduce the font size to \small and check if this is already sufficient to make your table narrow enough to fit into the available space.

Comment: If you insist on keeping the table wider than the textwidth while symmetrically letting it overflow into the left and right margin, you can make use of the changepage package as for example shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154766/134144

Comment: You should merge your codes fragments to one small, compact and compilable document ...

Comment: What's the purpose of `@{\extracolsep{5pt}}`? Why is each cell in the header row wrapped in a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{…}` cocoon? And what's the purpose of expressing the oldest, newest, and Q2 andQ3 years with three decimal digits?

Answer (score 2):

You not need to move table anyhere. Try the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{My huge table}
\label{tab:???}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lccccccc @{}}
    \hline \hline
Statistic   & {N} & {Mean}  & {St. Dev.} & {Min} 
            & {Pctl(25)}    & {Pctl(75)} & {Max} \\
    \hline
sqft\_living & 2,000 & 2,156.307 & 958.696 & 440 & 1,460 & 2,640 & 9,640 \\
view & 2,000 & 0.373 & 1.026 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
condition & 2,000 & 3.417 & 0.654 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
grade & 2,000 & 7.748 & 1.200 & 4 & 7 & 8 & 13 \\
yr\_built & 1,800 & 1,973.880 & 28.719 & 1,900.000 & 1,954.000 & 2,000.000 & 2,014.000 \\
yr\_renovated & 2,000 & 118.719 & 472.126 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2,015 \\
sqft\_living15 & 2,000 & 2,033.584 & 705.835 & 460 & 1,500 & 2,450 & 5,030 \\
price\_per\_sqft & 2,000 & 269.090 & 118.534 & 87.588 & 184.960 & 320.706 & 800.000 \\
lot\_to\_living & 2,000 & 7.154 & 15.580 & 0.544 & 2.403 & 6.488 & 281.229 \\
basement\_percent & 2,000 & 0.127 & 0.172 & 0 & 0 & 0.3 & 1 \\
\hline 
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show page layout)

In above MWE are:

- for table used `tabular*` environment, for which width is select `\textwidth`
- `\tabcolsep` is preset to zero
- actual size of `\tabcolsep` is left to calculation by instruction `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you get rid of the `\multicolumn{1}{c}` cocoons that are suffocating the contents of the header cells, get rid of the `@{\extracolsep{5pt}}` column-spacing directive, and get rid of the frankly absurd-looking decimal digits for the calendar year numbers in the min, max, Quart1, and Quart3 columns. With these adjustments, the table fits just fine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3} % just for this example
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{xxx} \label{tab:xxx}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\ttfamily}l *{7}{c} @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Statistic} & $N$ & Mean & St.\ Dev. & Min & Pctl(25) & Pctl(75) & Max \\
\midrule
sqft\_living & 2,000 & 2,156.307 & 958.696 & 440 & 1,460 & 2,640 & 9,640 \\
view & 2,000 & 0.373 & 1.026 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
condition & 2,000 & 3.417 & 0.654 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
grade & 2,000 & 7.748 & 1.200 & 4 & 7 & 8 & 13 \\
yr\_built & 1,800 & 1,973.88 & 28.72 & 1900 & 1954 & 2000 & 2014 \\
yr\_renovated & 2,000 & 118.719 & 472.126 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2015 \\ % why all the zeroes in this row?
sqft\_living15 & 2,000 & 2,033.584 & 705.835 & 460 & 1,500 & 2,450 & 5,030 \\
price\_per\_sqft & 2,000 & 269.09 & 118.53 & 87.59 & 184.96 & 320.71 & 800.00 \\
lot\_to\_living & 2,000 & 7.154 & 15.580 & 0.544 & 2.403 & 6.488 & 281.229 \\
basement\_percent & 2,000 & 0.127 & 0.172 & 0 & 0 & 0.3 & 1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```