# Scale image figure to page width

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I am using the following code to scale the image figure to the page width:

```
\begin{figure*}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.90\paperwidth]{mypdf.pdf}
    \caption{Caption goes here}
    \label{tautable}
    %   \vspace{-2mm}
\end{figure*}
```

However, the aforementioned code stretched the image on the right hand side (as shown in the figure below) regardless of using \centering and makes it look weird. How can I position it in the center correctly that the image is scaled evenly in all sides for 90% of the page width.

[image]

Comment: To clarify: You want your image to be wider than the textwidth and centered on the page, while protruding  into the left and right margin? If that's the case, you might be interested in [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/134144)

Comment: Personally, I would suggest redrawing the table with latex. If you use abbreviations in the column headers, the whole table would need less space while keeping a readable font size.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: @leandriis thank you for the solution and the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the final answer to this question as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{image}}%
  \caption{Caption goes here}
  \label{fig:key}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```