# How to overwrite margins for one table

Tags: tables

I have a table that is too long for it to fit under the current margins. Im wondering if there is possible to overwrite the margins for this table only so that it fits in on an a4 page, but not the rest of the text?

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{7}{c}}
    \toprule
    & & \thead{Obs.} & \thead{Mean} & \thead{Median} & \thead{Std.dev.} & \thead{p-value\\(diff. in means)} & \thead{p-value\\(diff. in medians}
    \\\midrule
Panel A. Matching Characteristics &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hspace{3mm}Log(assets) & Green Bond & 108 & 9.621 & 9.501 & 1.803 & 0.059 & 0.03  \\ 
    \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages to your code (See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: Although about centering an overly wide `figure`, the following question and its answers may be of interest for you: [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/134144). For some alternatives whith which you could make sure your table fits into the available space rather than letting it protrude into the margins, you may want to take a look at [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)

Answer (score 1):

With use of the `changepage` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                siunitx,
                varwidth}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep} % <---
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Caption},
  label = {tab:my_label},
note{a} = {SD: Standard Deviation},
note{b} = {$p$-value for Difference in means},
note{c} = {$p$-value for Difference in medians}
                ]{colspec = {@{}*{3}{Q[l]} c *{5}{X[c, m, si={table-format=1.3}]} @{}},
                   colsep = 3pt,
                   row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                  measure = vbox
                 }
    \toprule
 ~  &   &       & Obs.  & {{{Mean}}}
                                & {{{Median}}}
                                        & {{{SD\TblrNote{a} }}}   
                                                & {{{$p$\TblrNote{b} (mean)}}}  
                                                        & {{{$p$\TblrNote{c} (meadian)}}}   \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=3]{l} {Panel A:\\ Matching Characteristics}
    &   &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
    \hline[dashed]
    & Log(assets)
        & Green Bond
                & 108   & 9.621 & 9.501 & 1.803 & 0.059 & 0.03  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Answer (score 0):

Without further information such as `documentclass`, used `packages` and a detailed description of want you want, we can only guess what you are trying to achieve. I also don't understand the first column of your table. Does this come close to your desired output?

[image: example table]

This is generated by the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \makebox[\linewidth]{%
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={@{} l*{7}{c} @{}},
            row{1}={font=\bfseries, m},
        }
        \toprule
        & & Obs. & Mean & Median & Std.dev. & {p-value \\ (diff. in means)} & {p-value \\ (diff. in medians} \\
        \midrule
        {Panel A. Matching \\ Characteristics} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
        \hspace{3mm}Log(assets) & Green Bond & 108 & 9.621 & 9.501 & 1.803 & 0.059 & 0.03  \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Of course, I could only guess things like `documentclass` and `margin`, so please provide more information so we can help.

There are quite a few things not so great about this layout. It is just meant as a clarification for your question.