# Table placement got messed up by using `threeparttable`

Tags: tables, positioning, resize

I was just figuring out how to cite multiple lines to same footnote. I use `\usepackage{threeparttable}` to do so. However, the table I am making is quite large (over 70 lines), and this seems to have messed up with the `\centering` command. The table has shifted to the right.

Now, I am using resizebox to fit the whole thing into one page, and I am not comfortable picking random `\renewcommand` because I am not always sure what that could do to my specific case.

The table is still all in within the page, but I would really love to have it centered.

Here is minimum viable code, and part of the table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
% \usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{enumerate,color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{makecell}
% \usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
%\usepackage[sf,normalsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage[format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
% Packages used for title page layout
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
% \usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document
\begin{table}
      \centering
      {\small\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.8}
      \caption{Spá um raforkunotkun, forgangsorka og skerðanleg orka. Almenn notkun að meðtöldum dreifitöpum og núverandi og samþykktir nýir stórnotendur. \label{table:Orkuspá}}
      \resizebox{!}{.31\paperheight}{
      \begin{threeparttable}
      \begin{NiceTabular}{lcccccccccc}
    \hline
    \Block{2-1}{Ár} & \Block{1-2}{Úttekt frá dreifikerfinu\\ forgangs- og skerðanleg\\ orka með dreifitöpum} & & \Block{1-2}{Úttekt frá\\ flutningskerfinu} & & \Block{1-2}{Flutningstöp} & & \Block{1-2}{Úttekt frá \\ vinnslufyrirtækjum} & & \Block{1-2}{Samtals} \\
    & Orka GWh & Afl MW & Orka GWh & Afl MW & Orka GWh & Afl MW & Orka GWh & Afl MW & Orka GWh & Afl MW  \\
    \hline
    2015 \tnote{1} & 3.604,74 & 618,46 & 14.356,34 & 1.685,89 & 369,56 & 57,11 & 468,32 & 75,40 & 18.798,96 & 2.383,25 \\
    2016 \tnote{1} & 3.383,99 & 590,10 & 14.334,19 & 1.695,96 & 360,42 & 57,05 & 470,86 & 71,46 & 18.549,46 & 2.378,51 \\
    2017 \tnote{1} & 3.519,13 & 608,86 & 14.869,95 & 1.750,87 & 373,07 & 61,49 & 476,38 & 84,74 & 19.238,53 & 2.443,61 \\
    2018 \tnote{1} & 3.682,07 & 623,26 & 15.259,88 & 1.838,28 & 398,09 & 70,47 & 489,75 & 70,71 & 19.829,79 & 2.519,53 \\
    2019 \tnote{1} & 3.506,86 & 596,63 & 15.145,31 & 1.829,48 & 365,82 & 63,40 & 476,84 & 85,11 & 19.494,83 & 2.495,07 \\
    2020 \tnote{1} & 3.473,77 & 596,83 & 14.830,70 & 1.790,95 & 353,09 & 60,54 & 469,74 & 72,27 & 19.127,30 & 2.408,28 \\
    2021 & 3.688,10 & 630,47 & 15.539,59 & 1.865,64 & 397,70 & 67,72 & 479,82 & 73,82 & 20.105,21 & 2.584,89 \\
    2022 & 3.785,98 & 647,81 & 16.099,28 & 1.875,76 & 416,40 & 69,68 & 490,14 & 75,41 & 20.791,80 & 2.615,29 \\
   \hline
  \end{NiceTabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}
  \item[1] Rauntölur
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}}}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I am sorry if I come off as dry, I am just tired after long day, and that same footnote over many lines took way too much time to figure out.

Comment: [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/106162) might help?

Comment: Try `\scriptsize\tabcolsep=2pt` (after \caption).

Comment: Using `\resizebox` to cram the entire 11-column/70-row table into a single page pretty much *guarantees* that the font size will be so minuscule as to make material indecipherable. Would you be willing to render the table in landscape mode and have it span several pages?

Comment: @JohnKormylo This moves my table back into the center and the table is no longer flush to the right side of the page.

Comment: @Mico Unfortunately I am not looking for rendering the table in landscape. I have printed this out and the results are fine, no worries at all regarding illegibility. Neat solution though. Also for the information that needs to be displayed, it is not possible to reduce the wording in the top two columns :)

Answer (score 1):

The phenomenon you describe as "the table shifting to the right" is almost certainly an optical illusion, caused by the fact that the table is very wide due to its having 11 columns.

I would advise strongly against using either `\resizebox` or the `adjustbox` machinery to cram the table into a single page, as that trick will almost certainly result in the material being rendered so tiny as to make it utterly illegible and indecipherable.

Instead, I suggest you use one or more landscape-mode pages to render the table. Just how many are needed depends on how many rows the real table has.

The following screenshot shows the result of rendering the table provided in your code in a `sidewaystable` environment. Note that I've employed some of the machinery of the `siunitx` package to help auto-format the numerical data. If your table needs to be displayed across several `sidewaystable` environments, be sure to employ the `\ContinuedFloat` macro of the `\caption` package to help adjust the numbering of the table captions.

[image]

I'm afraid I don't understand Icelandic, but I can't help but remark that it might be useful if you made the sub-header above data columns 1 and 2 less, well, wordy. :-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{enumerate} %,color
\usepackage{xurl} % allow linebreaks at arbitrary points in a long URL string
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} % <-- use 'flushleft' option

\usepackage[format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
%%%%\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}


% new code: 
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} c @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

% \usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits =4,
         group-separator      ={.},
         output-decimal-marker={,}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercol. separation

\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Spá um raforkunotkun, forgangsorka og skerðanleg 
   orka. Almenn notkun að meðtöldum dreifitöpum og 
   núverandi og samþykktir nýir stórnotendur.\strut} 
   \label{table:Orkuspá}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l    
     T{4.2}T{3.2} 
     T{5.2}T{4.2} 
     *{2}{T{3.2}T{2.2}} 
     T{5.2}T{4.2} }
    \toprule
    Ár & 
    \mybox{Úttekt frá dreifikerfinu\\ 
           forgangs- og skerðanleg\\ 
           orka með dreifitöpum} & 
    \mybox{Úttekt frá\\ flutningskerfinu} & 
    \mybox{Flutningstöp} & 
    \mybox{Úttekt frá \\ vinnslufyrirtækjum} & 
    \mybox{Samtals} 
    \\
    \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} \cmidrule{10-11} 
    & {Orka GWh} & {Afl MW} 
    & {Orka GWh} & {Afl MW} 
    & {Orka GWh} & {Afl MW} 
    & {Orka GWh} & {Afl MW} 
    & {Orka GWh} & {Afl MW}  \\
   
    \midrule
    2015\tnote{1} & 3604,74 & 618,46 & 14356,34 & 1685,89 & 369,56 & 57,11 & 468,32 & 75,40 & 18798,96 & 2383,25 \\
    2016\tnote{1} & 3383,99 & 590,10 & 14334,19 & 1695,96 & 360,42 & 57,05 & 470,86 & 71,46 & 18549,46 & 2378,51 \\
    2017\tnote{1} & 3519,13 & 608,86 & 14869,95 & 1750,87 & 373,07 & 61,49 & 476,38 & 84,74 & 19238,53 & 2443,61 \\
    2018\tnote{1} & 3682,07 & 623,26 & 15259,88 & 1838,28 & 398,09 & 70,47 & 489,75 & 70,71 & 19829,79 & 2519,53 \\
    2019\tnote{1} & 3506,86 & 596,63 & 15145,31 & 1829,48 & 365,82 & 63,40 & 476,84 & 85,11 & 19494,83 & 2495,07 \\
    2020\tnote{1} & 3473,77 & 596,83 & 14830,70 & 1790,95 & 353,09 & 60,54 & 469,74 & 72,27 & 19127,30 & 2408,28 \\
    2021          & 3688,10 & 630,47 & 15539,59 & 1865,64 & 397,70 & 67,72 & 479,82 & 73,82 & 20105,21 & 2584,89 \\
    2022          & 3785,98 & 647,81 & 16099,28 & 1875,76 & 416,40 & 69,68 & 490,14 & 75,41 & 20791,80 & 2615,29 \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
  
\smallskip\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] Rauntölur
\end{tablenotes}
  
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A try to fit your table on portrait oriented page. By use of `talltblr` of `tabularray` package, which is offer functionalčity of the to classic `threeparttable`, with libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits =4,
         group-separator      ={.},
         output-decimal-marker={,}}
\newcommand\TN[1]{\TblrNote{#1}}
\usepackage[format=plain,
            labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon]{caption}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \SetTblrStyle{note}{font=\scriptsize}
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Spá um raforkunotkun, forgangsorka og skerðanleg orka. Almenn notkun að meðtöldum dreifitöpum og núverandi og samþykktir nýir stórnotendur.},
  label = {table:Orkuspá},
note{1} = {Rauntölur}
                ]{colsep = 2.9pt,
                  colspec = {@{} l  Q[c, si={table-format=4.2}]
                                    Q[c, si={table-format=3.2}]
                                    Q[c, si={table-format=5.2}]
                                    Q[c, si={table-format=4.2}]
                               *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=3.2}]
                                    Q[c, si={table-format=2.2}]}
                                    Q[c, si={table-format=5.2}]
                                    Q[c, si={table-format=4.2}] 
                             @{}},
                  row{1,2} = {guard, b}, 
                  hspan=even
                  }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Ár 
    &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {Úttekt frá dreifikerfinu\\ forgangsog skerðanleg\\ orka með dreifitöpum} 
        &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {Úttekt frá\\ flutningskerfinu} 
                &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Flutningstöp
                        &   &\SetCell[c=2]{c}    {Úttekt frá \\ vinnslufyrir-\\tækjum} 
                            &    &  \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Samtals   
                                    &                           \\
    \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{2-3} \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{4-5} \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{6-7} 
    \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{8-9} \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{10-11} 
    & {Orka\\ GWh}  & {Afl\\ MW} & {Orka\\ GWh} & {Afl\\ MW} 
    & {Orka\\ GWh}  & {Afl\\ MW} & {Orka\\ GWh} & {Afl\\ MW}
    & {Orka\\ GWh}  & {Afl\\ MW}                                \\
    \midrule
2015\TN{1}  & 3 604,74 & 618,46 & 14 356,34 & 1 685,89 & 369,56 & 57,11 & 468,32 & 75,40 & 18 798,96 & 2 383,25 \\
2016\TN{1}  & 3 383,99 & 590,10 & 14 334,19 & 1 695,96 & 360,42 & 57,05 & 470,86 & 71,46 & 18 549,46 & 2 378,51 \\
2017\TN{1}  & 3 519,13 & 608,86 & 14 869,95 & 1 750,87 & 373,07 & 61,49 & 476,38 & 84,74 & 19 238,53 & 2 443,61 \\
2018\TN{1}  & 3 682,07 & 623,26 & 15 259,88 & 1 838,28 & 398,09 & 70,47 & 489,75 & 70,71 & 19 829,79 & 2 519,53 \\
2019\TN{1}  & 3 506,86 & 596,63 & 15 145,31 & 1 829,48 & 365,82 & 63,40 & 476,84 & 85,11 & 19 494,83 & 2 495,07 \\
2020\TN{1}  & 3 473,77 & 596,83 & 14 830,70 & 1 790,95 & 353,09 & 60,54 & 469,74 & 72,27 & 19 127,30 & 2 408,28 \\
2021        & 3 688,10 & 630,47 & 15 539,59 & 1 865,64 & 397,70 & 67,72 & 479,82 & 73,82 & 20 105,21 & 2 584,89 \\
2022        & 3 785,98 & 647,81 & 16 099,28 & 1 875,76 & 416,40 & 69,68 & 490,14 & 75,41 & 20 791,80 & 2 615,29 \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason I get an error `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `guard'` My `xcolor` package is set up like yours in this document...

Comment: @ÓlafurVíðirGuðbjargarson, I tested my <<mwe again, It works as it is. Important is, that you not change table preamble. BTW, I don't know, if hyphenation of "vinnslufyrirtækjum" is correct. It should be done manually.

Comment: I just found out that `siunitx` doesn't seem to be installed through my TexLive package, Trying to figure out how to install from github, but this specific package does not include how to install (use make or run specific command).

Comment: @ÓlafurVíðirGuðbjargarson, `siunitx` is in CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en . I'm not familiar with TeXLive, but it probably has a vizard for uploading of new packages.

Comment: Yeah, I see it on CTAN, rinning linux and I am not familiar with CTAN packages or how to install them. Most of the packages I use I have found in the AUR.

Comment: @ÓlafurVíðirGuðbjargarson, on CTAN you can find https://ctan.org/pkg/texlive. There is some description about TeXlive. It may help you.

Comment: @ÓlafurVíðirGuðbjargarson, BTW, check which version of `tabularray` you have. The last is 2023A

Comment: I'll do that when I have cleaned installed TexLive, Doing it manually now, and will take some time. Should give me the ability to install siunitx directly from CTAN.

Comment: This is unfortunately not working, When I install siunitx, I get `tlmgr install: package already present: siunitx` but when I compile latex I get `File `siunitx.sty' not found.`. I am at a loss here

Comment: OK, fixed the `File: siunitx.sty not found` but now it won't read the numbers..... I am giving up on this. :D

Comment: @ÓlafurVíðirGuðbjargarson, sorry to hear this. I can't solve remotely your LaTeX  installation problems. For sure the proposed solutions (as mine as of Mico) are not source of your problem .  It may be a time to reinstall it or use Overleaf service.

Comment: I know.... I have no idea why this is acting like this, but I was able to revert to last working solution. So I will use that. Thank you for your help @Zarko I am a bit sad that this method didn't work for me.

Comment: I noticed that in your code, the numbers are differently formatted, could that be the case?

Comment: @ÓlafurVíðirGuðbjargarson, no. I just test my MWE also on Overleaf. It works as expected: fine.  For local compilation on your PC, apparently you need to resolve remedy in your LaTeX installation (thoroughly uninstall it and them make fresh installing).

Comment: it's fine, just need this for my thesis. After that I'll probably make a clean install of OS and maybe latex as well.