# Aligning multiple images in the same page

Tags: graphics, margins, alignment

I have 3/4th of a page left to align 4 images. I am on a page constraint and want to fit them all properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{sample}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/edaaml1.jpg}
        \caption{AMLSim: All transactions in each timestep}
        \label{fig:16}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figures/edaaml2.jpg}
        \caption{AMLSim: SAR transactions in each timestep}
        \label{fig:17}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.32]{Figures/edaellip.jpg}
        \caption{Elliptic: All transactions in each timestep}
        \label{fig:18}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{Figures/edaellip2.jpg}
        \caption{Elliptic: Illicit transaction graph in timestep 41}
        \label{fig:19}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks so far:

[image]

The problem is that the images are too small (trying to be fit in one page) and the captions too congested. The margin spaces can be reduced to accommodate them, but can I only change the margins in this page (I don't want to ruin the alignment in the rest of the document), or is there a grid for images I can appropriately adjust these figures in?

Comment: Is this a [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) presentation?

Comment: No, it is just a report.

Comment: So please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) instead of only a code snippet. Currently we even do not know, what this `frame` environment is. LaTeX kernel provides a (robust) `\frame` command (used for the `\framebox` command of `picture` environment), but no `frame` environment. And for me it is also not clear, what you expect. Do you want to enlarge the images and have them [protrude into the left and right page margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582)? Or do you want to enlarge the page into the bottom margin?

Comment: I have added edits to the latex code to show a minimal working example. My question was if there was a way to increase the margins only for one page in an entire document to fit all 4 images in a grid-like format. Or if there any commands or packages that can help me do the same (adjust 4 images in 3/4th of a page).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessing, that you after something like this:

[image]

For above image is used `framed` package. Frame is deawn inside float `figure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{framed}   % for frame around images

\author{Me!}
\title{sample}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[ht]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{framed}  % <--
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}% {Figures/edaaml1.jpg}
        \caption{AMLSim: All transactions in each timestep}
        \label{fig:16}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}% {Figures/edaaml2.jpg}
        \caption{AMLSim: SAR transactions in each timestep}
        \label{fig:17}
    \end{minipage}\\

\medskip  
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}% {Figures/edaellip.jpg}
        \caption{Elliptic: All transactions in each timestep}
        \label{fig:18}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}% {Figures/edaellip2.jpg}
        \caption{Elliptic: Illicit transaction graph in timestep 41}
        \label{fig:19}
    \end{minipage}
\end{framed}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
or you looking for the following:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout).

In this case figures protrude outer border for amount of `\marginparwidth+\marginparsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\author{Me!}
\title{sample}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}% {Figures/edaaml1.jpg}
        \caption{AMLSim: All transactions in each timestep}
        \label{fig:16}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}% {Figures/edaaml2.jpg}
        \caption{AMLSim: SAR transactions in each timestep}
        \label{fig:17}
    \end{minipage}\\

\medskip
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}% {Figures/edaellip.jpg}
        \caption{Elliptic: All transactions in each timestep}
        \label{fig:18}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}% {Figures/edaellip2.jpg}
        \caption{Elliptic: Illicit transaction graph in timestep 41}
        \label{fig:19}
    \end{minipage}
\end{adjustwidth*}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[1][3-7]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions! It works using the first option.