# How to put two figures side by side in a two-column document

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column

How to put two figures side by side in a two-column document. `figure*` is not working.

Comment: Related: [Two figures side by side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side), [Place figures side by side, spill into outer margin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/place-figures-side-by-side-spill-into-outer-margin). Try the solutions there and replace `figure` with `figure*` for a two-column document.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I used subfigure package:

```
\begin{figure*}[htp]
  \centering
  \subfigure[random caption 1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.38]{image1}}\quad
  \subfigure[random caption 2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.38]{image2}}
\end{figure*}
```

Worked flawlessly :)

Comment: The `subfigure` package is the way to go if both are subfigure from one figure, i.e. a) and b) and should be labeled as such. However often two different, independent figures should be set side-by-side because of place limitations. Then your method doesn't work. You should prefer `width` for `scale`. I would also use `\hfill` instead of `\quad` to spread the two figure over the text width.

Comment: That's true, but it does the job :)

And I agree \hfill align the pictures better...

Comment: Not for me. The scaling has to be adjusted for each image and the horizontal alignment is not correct. I'm sorry, I just to pedantic in such things :-)

Comment: The [subfigure](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) package is obsolete. One of its successors is [subfig](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig).

Answer (score 31):

This should do:

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
<Code for the first figure>
\caption{Caption}\label{label-a}
\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
<Code for the second figure>
\caption{Caption}\label{label-b}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: +1 That's the way I do it for two independent figures, i.e. there aren't subfigures. However I normally use `width=.49\textwidth` and `\hfill` not `\qquad` between them. Having a fixed distance is not a good idea IMHO.

Comment: @Martin: this depends on the size of the figures; also, with just one `\hfill` in the middle the figures will go to the margins and maybe this is not wanted. However it was worth noting.

Comment: @egrep: Sorry, with `width=.49\textwidth` I meant using `.49\textwidth` in the width argument of `minipage`. Of course the width depends on the figures, someone might want to have e.g. 70-30 ratio, but I find .49-`\hfill`-.49 much better and less size dependent than .4-`\qquad`-.4. For me this doesn't push the figure in the margin: .49+.49=.98 => `\hfill` will be .02. Of course if the content is wider than the outer `minipage` than you are in trouble. IMHO using a fixed distance like `\quad`, `\qquad` or `\hspace{...}` causes more trouble, but I guess its also a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Is there any way to `\label` then `\ref` the figures?

Comment: @Geoff Isn't there a `\label` command?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. You do not need any extra packages, such as subfigure or subcaption.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{filename1}
\caption{default}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{filename2}
\caption{default}
\label{fig:figure2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```