# How to put algorithm and figure side by side in two column document?

Tags: floats, positioning, captions, algorithms

I want to put two figures and an algorithm side by side in a two-column document, and the figures and the algorithm should span two columns.

I have surveyed previously asked questions such as [How to put algorithm and figure(s) side by side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34875/how-to-put-algorithm-and-figures-side-by-side) and [How to put two figures side by side in a two-column document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16868/how-to-put-two-figures-side-by-side-in-a-two-column-document) do not answer my question.

The following is a MWE, which includes templates for figures and alorithm that I use. If you are trying to run the code, please re-name whatever `eps` figures you get to `xx.esp` and `yy.eps` in the same directory with the following document.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}

\title{xxx}


\maketitle


\begin{figure*}[!t]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[htp]{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{xx.eps}
    \vspace{-0.4cm}%
    \caption{THis is figure xx}\label{fig:xx}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[htp]{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{yy.eps}
    \vspace{-0.4cm}%
    \caption{This is figure yy.}\label{fig:yy}
  \end{minipage}
  \vspace{-0.6cm}%
\end{figure*}



\vspace{-0.2cm}%
\alglanguage{pseudocode}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\small
\caption{\small Insert item into Hash Table (with mCBF and aCBF)}
\label{Algorithm:insert_mCBF_aCBF}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{$\mathbf{InsertItem}$}{item $x$}
    \For {$i = 1 \to k$}
            \State $mCBF.C_{f_i(x)\%N}$ ++
    \EndFor
    \State $C_{min} = MAX\_VALUE$
    %\Comment{Get minimum value of $k$ counters in mCBF}
    \For {$i = 1 \to k$}
        \If {$C_{min} > mCBF.C_{f_i(x)\%N}$}
            \State $C_{min} \gets mCBF.C_{f_i(x)\%N}$
            \State $j \gets f_i(x)\%N$
            \State $m \gets i$
        \EndIf
    \EndFor
    %\State $C_{min} = min\{mCBF.C_{f_1(x)\%N},\cdot\cdot\cdot,mCBF.C_{f_k(x)\%N}\}$
    %\State $i = \textbf{SubscriptOf}(C_{min})$
    \State $B_j = B_j \cup x$
    \Comment \emph{Insert $x$ into $B_j$}
    \For {$i = 1 \to k$}
            \State $aCBF_m.C_{f_i(x)\%\textbf{LengthOf}(aCBF_m)}$ ++
    \EndFor
\EndProcedure
\Statex
\end{algorithmic}
  \vspace{-0.4cm}%
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

I know that the asterisk (*) is meant to make the figures span two colums, but the inside `minipage` does not allow me to add the `algorithm`. Moreover, even if the `minipage` allows, the `algorithm` would be in a `figure` environment, which would conflict. Please help.

Edit: I upload a picture that shows what I want looks like. The two figures and the algorithm are in the same line, but span two columns.

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I get a `Language 'pseudocode' is not yet defined!` error when I run your code.

Comment: @JohnWickerson Load the `algpseudocode` package after the other packages. Other problems with the code provided here include: no `document` environment, and a `\LineComment` command that is nowhere defined.

Comment: @Jubobs Ah. In which case I had better wait for Bloodmoon to provide a complete document!

Comment: @Jubobs  I am so sorry! I have updated the Minimun Working Example. I took for granted that you guys may have the packages I use. Please help!

Comment: @JohnWickerson  I am so sorry! I have updated the Minimun Working Example. I took for granted that you guys may have the packages I use. Please help!

Comment: I wonder, could you provide a picture (a rough hand-drawn one would suffice) to show what you want the result to look like? Because I'm not entirely clear on what you want. For instance, you say "two figures and an algorithm side by side" -- does that mean three things all in one row?

Comment: @JohnWickerson Yes, the three things are all in one row. I have upload a pic. to show what I want. Thanks!

Comment: There's an answer **[here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16869/25356)** that gives some simple code for putting multiple figures side-by-side. Supposing for a moment that your `algorithm` were just another `figure`, does that work for you? And if so, then perhaps the problem has to do with the `algorithm`.

Comment: @JohnWickerson that does not work for me. `algorithm` is not `figure`, I cannot put an `algorithm` within a '\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}' environment. If this is allowed, will the caption be FIGURE or ALGORITHM?

Comment: @Martin Scharrer would you please help me?

Comment: @MartinScharrer would you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newcounter{tmp}

\begin{document}

\title{xxx}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{xx.eps}}
    \vspace{-0.4cm}%
    \caption{THis is figure xx}\label{fig:xx}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{yy.eps}}
    \vspace{-0.4cm}%
    \caption{This is figure yy.}\label{fig:yy}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
\alglanguage{pseudocode}
\renewcommand\figurename{Algorithm}
\setcounter{tmp}{\value{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{\value{algorithm}}
\small
\caption{\small Insert item into Hash Table (with mCBF and aCBF)}
\label{Algorithm:insert_mCBF_aCBF}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{$\mathbf{InsertItem}$}{item $x$}
    \For {$i = 1 \to k$}
            \State $mCBF.C_{f_i(x)\%N}$ ++
    \EndFor
    \State $C_{min} = MAX\_VALUE$
    %\Comment{Get minimum value of $k$ counters in mCBF}
    \For {$i = 1 \to k$}
        \If {$C_{min} > mCBF.C_{f_i(x)\%N}$}
            \State $C_{min} \gets mCBF.C_{f_i(x)\%N}$
            \State $j \gets f_i(x)\%N$
            \State $m \gets i$
        \EndIf
    \EndFor
    %\State $C_{min} = min\{mCBF.C_{f_1(x)\%N},\cdot\cdot\cdot,mCBF.C_{f_k(x)\%N}\}$
    %\State $i = \textbf{SubscriptOf}(C_{min})$
    \State $B_j = B_j \cup x$
    \Comment \emph{Insert $x$ into $B_j$}
    \For {$i = 1 \to k$}
            \State $aCBF_m.C_{f_i(x)\%\textbf{LengthOf}(aCBF_m)}$ ++
    \EndFor
\EndProcedure
\Statex
\end{algorithmic}
\end{minipage}
  \setcounter{figure}{\value{tmp}}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: I eventually get an answer! Yes, it works! But I have more than one algorithms in my document, and the caption field in this answer has changed. How can I get the same caption filed as that in the right-most of the picture in the question?

Comment: @Bloodmoon please see Section *B. Algorithms* on page 10 of the [IEEEtranHOWTO document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf); the use of the `algorithm` floating environment is not recommended when using this document class.