# How to have a figure touch the edge of the page?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, margins

How can I position a figure (picture) so that it:

- is aligned on the left-hand side with the text (this is in two column page)
- touches (or exceeds) the right-hand side of the page?

An example can be found here: http://library.fes.de/pdf-files/akademie/berlin/04801.pdf (go to any page with a picture and see how the picture is placed.)
Note: The example is not what I would call pretty; I think the design is hideous. None the less, I'd like to know how to accomplish this style design for pictures.

Comment: See [Place figures side by side, spill into outer margin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/place-figures-side-by-side-spill-into-outer-margin). You need to use `\makebox[\columnwidth][r]{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\columnwidth+\rightmargin\relax]{image}}` in this case. I'm not sure about the margin length, though.

Comment: @Martin: sorry, but `\rightmargin` is definitely wrong; it's a parameter for lists.

Comment: @egreg: Indeed, but the principle stands.

Comment: Related but for centering: [Centering a box independent of documents margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435633/2975)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\newcommand{\mydimright}{%
  \dimexpr\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin-
  \columnwidth-\columnsep\relax}
\newcommand{\mydimleft}{%
  \dimexpr1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+\columnwidth\relax}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{flushleft}
\makebox[\columnwidth][r]{%
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=\mydimleft]{try}}
\end{flushleft}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{flushleft}
\makebox[\columnwidth][l]{%
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=\mydimright]{try}}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

There is no immediate access to the right margin width, which has to be computed in an indirect way.

With the command `\layout` of the layout package, one can look at the relevant lengths. I've put also `\hoffset`, because some classes might change it.

Here `try` is the graphic file I always use for tests. I've used `flushleft` just in order to avoid LaTeX trying to be smart with figure placement.

-- **Extended version for automatic placement in the figure environment** --

Here it is, following Martin's suggestion; the command `\touchmarginincludegraphics` works like its sibling `\includegraphics` except, of course, that the keyword `width` should not be specified.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\def\tmig@r{\dimexpr\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-
  \oddsidemargin-\columnwidth-\columnsep\relax}
\def\tmig@l{\dimexpr1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+\columnwidth\relax}
\newcommand{\touchmarginincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \if@firstcolumn
    \def\tmig@place{r}%
  \else
    \def\tmig@place{l}%
  \fi
  \makebox[\columnwidth][\tmig@place]{%
    \includegraphics[#1,width=\@nameuse{tmig@\tmig@place}]{#2}}
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!h]
\touchmarginincludegraphics[height=1cm]{try}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{figure}[!h]
\touchmarginincludegraphics[height=1cm]{try}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The images in the linked PDF look like floats to me. You might want to update your code to insert `\begin{figure}[t]` and use `\if@firstcolumn` to select the direction.

Comment: @Martin: I've added the code, thanks for suggesting `\if@firstcolumn`.

Comment: Thank you, that works! I removed the height=1cm option, that makes the aspect ratio stay.

Comment: @Unapiedra: Yes, the `height=1cm` was there just to make a one page example with figures in both columns.