# Centering a box independent of documents margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage, geometry, adjustbox

Is there a way to center a box (for example, `adjustbox`) even if the documents margins are not equal (left and right)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.99\paperwidth,margin=0pt,center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustbox}

\newgeometry{left=250pt,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,includefoot}
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.99\paperwidth,margin=0pt,center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Centred w.r.t. what? The sheet of paper width?

Comment: this should be relevant (and a possible duplicate): [Center figure that is wider than `\textwidth`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582)

Comment: If the problem is the one @barbarabeeton suggests, I find lying is generally the most straightforward and most effective solution if the figure is too wide. (Height/depth is a bit different.)

Comment: Related: [How to have a figure touch the edge of the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18166/2975)

Answer (score 2):

You can put it inside a tikz node with position `(current page.center)` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz} 


\begin{document}



\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\paperwidth,margin=0pt,center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \node[text width=0.7*\linewidth] at (current page.center)
    {\lipsum[2]};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}


\newgeometry{left=250pt,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,includefoot}


 \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\paperwidth,margin=0pt,center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
 \node[text width=0.7*\linewidth] at (current page.center)
 {\lipsum[2]};
 \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{adjustbox}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the newest version of `adjustbox` v1.2 from 2019/01/04 you can use the `pagecenter` key to align the content centered on the page. This uses the code in my original answer internally (i.e. lapping the content to the left depending on the page margin).

```
\documentclass[twopages]{book}
\usepackage{adjustbox}[2019/01/04]
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.95\paperwidth,frame,pagecenter,vspace=\medskipamount}
\blindtext
\end{adjustbox}

\blindtext

\clearpage
\blindtext

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.95\paperwidth,frame,pagecenter,vspace=\medskipamount}
\blindtext
\end{adjustbox}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

---

#### Original answer which works with older versions of `adjustbox`:

If you want to center the box on the page, not the text area, one way to do this is to make it `lap` into the left text margin of the page. The required dimensions can be read using the `layout` package.

The following code uses the `ifoddpage` package together with `adjustbox` to get the right amount.

```
\documentclass[twopages]{book}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\checkoddpage
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.95\paperwidth,vspace=\smallskipamount,frame,
lap={\textwidth}{-1in-\hoffset-\ifoddpage\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi+.5\paperwidth-.5\width-\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname}}
\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustbox}

\lipsum

\checkoddpage
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.95\paperwidth,vspace=\smallskipamount,frame,
lap={\textwidth}{-1in-\hoffset-\ifoddpage\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi+.5\paperwidth-.5\width-\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname}}
\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustbox}

\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\layout


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: As I liked the idea I now added this as `centerpage` key as well as `\centerpagebox` macro and `centerpagebox` to [the `adjustbox` package](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/adjustbox/commits/d3b553420f8f5ec9c24d355777b951f5fa17cb77). It will be published with the next release.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear exactly what you are centering on, but you can use the adjustwith command from the changepage package to temporarily adjust margins.

The command takes two arguments for left and right margin respectively. The value is the amount by which the text block will be REDUCED (so negative values enlarge). The effect is on linewidth not textwidth.

The below MWE and output together with some reading should explain.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
 \usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{left=100pt,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,includefoot}

\begin{center}
    Center within margins
\end{center}    
Left
\flushright Right

\newgeometry{left=200pt,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,includefoot}

\begin{center}
    Center within margins
\end{center}    
\begin{adjustwidth}{-100pt}{0pt}
    \begin{center}
        Center on temporarily adjusted margin
    \end{center}    
Left
\flushright Right
\end{adjustwidth}

\newgeometry{left=300pt,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,includefoot}

\begin{center}
    Center within margins
\end{center}    
\begin{adjustwidth}{-200pt}{0pt}
    \begin{center}
        Center on temporarily adjusted margin
    \end{center}    
Text
\flushright Right
\end{adjustwidth}

\newgeometry{left=400pt,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,includefoot}

\begin{center}
    Center within margins
\end{center}    
\begin{adjustwidth}{-300pt}{0pt}
    \begin{center}
        Center on temporarily adjusted margin
    \end{center}    
Text
\flushright Right
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible to automate slightly but depends what you are centering on. Manual use may be easiest when you understand how it works. Obviously if you have different margins on odd and even pages that needs taking into account as well.