# How to have a figure touch the top edge of the page?

Tags: graphics, positioning, alignment, page

I want to have a letterhead format with the corporate logo at the very top of the paper. I have figured out how the fill the graphics with the full breadth of the page with the information on this webpage-
[How to have a figure touch the edge of the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18166/how-to-have-a-figure-touch-the-edge-of-the-page).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

%
\newcommand{\dimtorightedge}{%
  \dimexpr\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin\relax}
%

\begin{flushleft}
        \mbox
        {%
            \makebox[\dimtorightedge]{}%
            \makebox[0pt][r]
            {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{logo}}%
        }
\end{flushleft}

\section{A test section}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

I got the result like this -
[image]

However I'm still struggling to align the top side of the graphics (logo) with the top edge of the paper.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I have not found anything anywhere putting the graphics right to the very top of the page. I want this for the first page for now. But might also want every page afterwards. It does not matter whether it's implemented with the header or in the 'body' of the article. (Of course it's more elegant with header if it's a letter header). Thanks.
I can think of an ugly workaround by making a blank pdg page with header with word and then include in TeX. But that's really ugly workaround and hope to see more elegant ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to raise the image into the upper margin. This can be done using `\raisebox`. I used the `layout` package with the `\layout` macro to display all length used by LaTeX to create the top of the page. The distance is `1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep`. You need to use the optional argument to set the new height by subtracting that value from the original height, which is defined as `\height` here. This also works if put into a header by simply removing `\headheight` and `\headsep` from the equation.

Of course you can also my `adjustbox` package to do all this with less code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\newcommand{\dimtorightedge}{%
  \dimexpr\paperwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin\relax}

\newcommand{\dimtotop}{%
  \dimexpr\height-1in-\voffset-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep\relax}


\begin{document}

\clearpage
\begin{flushleft}
        \hbox
        {%
            \makebox[\dimtorightedge]{}%
            \makebox[0pt][r]
            {\raisebox{0pt}[\dimtotop]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}}}%
        }
\end{flushleft}

\section{A test section}
\lipsum[4]

\clearpage
\noindent\adjustimage{width=\paperwidth,
    lap={\textwidth}{-1in-\hoffset-\ifoddpage\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi+.5\paperwidth-.5\width-\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname}, % adjustbox version v1.2 2019/01/04 provides this as 'pagecenter' key
    set height=\height-1in-\voffset-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep}{example-image}

\section{A test section}
\lipsum[4]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Martin. That's exactly what I wanted. Seems like I had not fully understood the command `\raisebox`. I was also not aware of the \height command - I had overlooked the \height command (and `\width`, `\depth`, as well) in the book 'The not so short introduction to LaTeX2e'.

Comment: @Max: `\height`, `\width` and `\depth` are defined internally by `\raisebox` when processing the length values. Also the `adjustbox` package does the same.

Comment: Oh you showed 2 ways of doing it. That's awesome. Thanks!

Comment: @Max: The `adjustbox` update from last week makes the horizontal adjustment easier, just replace the `lap=...` stuff with a simple `pagecenter`. I didn't used it yet, as not everyone might have the update yet.

Comment: Having learned from Martin's code, I also changed the `\dimtorightedge` definition by replacing `oddsidemargin` with`\ifoddpage\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi` to add more flexibility. But I don't see any problem with the simpler definition without changing the default page layout.

Comment: @Max: Note that `\ifoddpage` needs the `ifoddpage` package AND a `\checkoddpage` call just beforehand, best inside the same horizontal box to avoid possible page breaks just between it. This is not really required for `onside` documents, just for `twoside`. Better is actually to use `\ifoddpageoroneside` as `onside` documents only use `\oddsidemargin`.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. But my code with `\ifoddpage` worked fine without using package `ifoddpage`. 
Another try, I used `douvleside` without `\ifoddpage`, also seemed fine.

Comment: @Max: Well, `adjustbox` loads `ifoddpage` internally, that why its works. Nevertheless `\ifoddpage` shows the value of the last `\checkoddpage` use, not of the position it is used. Not using `\ifoddpage` might work in some but not in all cases, depending on the position and overall settings.