# Position an image to touch edges of page?

Tags: graphics, positioning

I'm trying to position an image to touch the right and bottom edges of the page. It's for a subtle background image. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Does this work https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167719/how-to-use-background-image-in-latex, or are you requiring something else?

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I can use the eso-pic package.

Comment: This question might also be relevant: [How to have a figure touch the top edge of the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469300/2975)