# Wide figures to spill out into the outer, not inner, margin in double-sided documents

Tags: floats, double-sided

I'm writing a text where I have some figures that need to be wider than the text width, and I want then to spill out into the outer (in my text, rather wide) margin. I have tried a solution which I found in a previous question here, but I can't make it work.

I copied the code in [Place figures side by side, spill into outer margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/place-figures-side-by-side-spill-into-outer-margin)

and modified it to:

```
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\begin{figure}
  \checkoddpage
  \edef\side{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi}%
  \makebox[\textwidth][\side]{\includegraphics[width=1.4\textwidth]{wide_image}}
     \caption{xxx}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

This makes figures behave the correct way on odd pages (they are left-aligned with text), but not on even pages (where they are still left-aligned with the text, making them spill into the inner margin instead)?

I'm using the "report" class.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ok, it is not so minimal, unfortunately, and now playing around I noticed that the error may appear on odd or even pages...

Comment: @carina Well, the problem is that your code is not a full document, so we cannot copy it into our TeX editors and compile it. If you need some "dummy text", you can use the package `\usepackage{lipsum}` and the command `\lipsum[1-5]`. If you change `[1-5]` to something else (up to 40), you get a text of different length. This would allow you to move the figures on odd or even page as needed.

Comment: yes, I see that, I'll try to make an example which shows the error. In short documents it seems to work for me, I notice now, but I'll see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: As well, you have to run it twice! to get the correct result.

Comment: yes, I ran it many times. Ok, I now noticed when reducing my example, that taking away "\usepackage{changepage} seems to make it work, at least in the instances I have now tried. Don't understand why, but still good.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see any problem here:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{geometry,caption}
\geometry{showframe=true,includemp,marginparwidth=5cm,marginparsep=1em}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false,width=\textwidth}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\checkoddpage
\makebox[\textwidth][\ifoddpage l\else r\fi]{\rule{1.4\textwidth}{3cm}}
\caption{xxx} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\clearpage%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{figure}
  \checkoddpage
  \makebox[\textwidth][\ifoddpage l\else r\fi]{\rule{1.4\textwidth}{3cm}}
     \caption{xxx}\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: even page]

[image: odd page]

Answer (score 2):

*(Too long for a comment.)*

There is a comment by [Konrad Rudolph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/42/konrad-rudolph) to the first answer in the question you linked:

[Place figures side by side, spill into outer margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/place-figures-side-by-side-spill-into-outer-margin#comment18252_10507)

> Small precaution for other users of this
>   solution: sometimes it won’t work. To fix this, pass the option `strict`
>   to the package or put `\strictpagecheck` before the `\checkoddpage`.

Maybe this is the reason why it doesn't work for you?