# How to have headers, section headings, and figures expand into the margin?

Tags: sectioning, floats, header-footer, margins, geometry

I am interested in the  following page layout.

[image]

1. How to have headers in margins (up to margin)
2. Is it possible to start section headings from margin
3. How to set figures occupy the margins.

I can make an MWE as given below

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}

%\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
%{\normalfont
%\sffamily\bfseries\filleft}
%{}{0pt}{}
%\titlespacing{\section}
%{4pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}

\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in+\hoffset\relax}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\llap{\hspace*{-\mylen}\thesection\hfill}}{0em}{}
  [{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{%
    \hspace*{-\mylen}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+\mylen\relax}{1pt}}}]

%titleps is alternate for fancyhdr
%
\usepackage{titleps}

%\newpagestyle{main}[\small\sffamily]{
\newpagestyle{main}{
\widenhead[4pc][0pt]{4pc}{0pt} %for scrbook
%\widenhead[6pc][0pt]{0pt}{6pc} %for scrbook
%\widenhead[0pt][6pc]{6pc}{0pt} %for scrartcl
\headrule
\sethead
[\textbf{\thepage}]
[\textsl{Title of the Book}]
[]
{}
{\textsl{\chaptertitle}}
{\textbf{\thepage}}
}
\pagestyle{main}

\renewpagestyle{plain}[\small\sffamily]{
%\footrule
%\setfoot[\textbf{\thepage}]
\setfoot
[]
[]
[]
{}
{}
%{\textbf{\thepage}}
{}
%
\sethead
[\textbf{\thepage}]
[\textsl{Title of the Book}]
[]
{}
{}
{\textbf{\thepage}}
}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\clearpage

\section{Section title}


skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk

sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf

\section{ Section title}

%
\begin{figure}[hb]
%\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{}
%\label{fig:p6a}
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}
%


skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk

sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk

\clearpage

\section{title}
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf    

\end{document}
```

The output : 
Even page
[image]

Odd page
[image]

> I want change the figure position to the margin...

Possible Solution
[Place figures side by side, spill into outer margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/place-figures-side-by-side-spill-into-outer-margin/10507#10507)

Comment: I made your title a bit more specific, hope you don’t mind.

Comment: You can have a look at [tufte-latex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex), see for instance the [sample book (360kB)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-book.pdf).

Comment: The manual of `fancyhdr` shows how this can be done.

Comment: @egreg I have used "titleps" to increase the headers width...

Comment: also you could take a look at [floatrow](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package for caption (and figure i guess) placement...

Comment: We have new package sidenotes with figure* and table* options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fix includes several points:

1) `\usepackage{calc}`

2) New caption definition to make it left justified:

```
\newcommand\mycaption[1]{\caption{%
  \leftskip-\mylen#1\protect\rule{\textwidth-\mylen}{0in}}}
```

3) `\leftskip` the margin for the figure environment

```
\begin{figure}[hb]
\setlength\leftskip{\leftskip-\mylen}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{}
\mycaption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}
```

Caveat:  I didn't fix your pre-existing problem with margins on page 3.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}

%\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
%{\normalfont
%\sffamily\bfseries\filleft}
%{}{0pt}{}
%\titlespacing{\section}
%{4pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}

\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in+\hoffset\relax}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\llap{\hspace*{-\mylen}\thesection\hfill}}{0em}{}
  [{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{%
    \hspace*{-\mylen}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+\mylen\relax}{1pt}}}]

%titleps is alternate for fancyhdr
%
\usepackage{titleps}

%\newpagestyle{main}[\small\sffamily]{
\newpagestyle{main}{
\widenhead[4pc][0pt]{4pc}{0pt} %for scrbook
%\widenhead[6pc][0pt]{0pt}{6pc} %for scrbook
%\widenhead[0pt][6pc]{6pc}{0pt} %for scrartcl
\headrule
\sethead
[\textbf{\thepage}]
[\textsl{Title of the Book}]
[]
{}
{\textsl{\chaptertitle}}
{\textbf{\thepage}}
}
\pagestyle{main}

\renewpagestyle{plain}[\small\sffamily]{
%\footrule
%\setfoot[\textbf{\thepage}]
\setfoot
[]
[]
[]
{}
{}
%{\textbf{\thepage}}
{}
%
\sethead
[\textbf{\thepage}]
[\textsl{Title of the Book}]
[]
{}
{}
{\textbf{\thepage}}
}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\clearpage

\section{Section title}


skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk

sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf

\section{ Section title}

\newcommand\mycaption[1]{\caption{%
  \leftskip-\mylen#1\protect\rule{\textwidth-\mylen}{0in}}}
%
\begin{figure}[hb]
\setlength\leftskip{\leftskip-\mylen}
%\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{}
%\label{fig:p6a}
\mycaption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}
%

skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk

sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk

\clearpage

\section{title}
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf skjdfh jhsdf sdfk
sdfsdf    

\end{document}
```

[image]