# Koma-script scrpage2 footer height

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, geometry, scrpage2

After lots of googling and hair-tearing, I'm turning grey and old, and no
wiser...

EDIT : see bottom for a half-cooked solution.

I switched from LaTeX plain classes (`article`, `report`, etc.) to Koma-Script.
And from `fancyhdr` to `scrpage2`/`scrheadings` for headers and footers.

Problem is, I utterly fails to properly manage the footer position and height.
I banged my head on the same problem for the headers, and found the
`headheight` option which solved this point. Not so for the footer.

Minimal example :

```
\documentclass[headheight=1.2cm,headsepline,footsepline,footbotline]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont\sffamily}

\ihead{}
\chead{}
\ohead{
  Line 1 \\ Line 2 \\ Line 3\\Line 4
}

\ifoot{}
\cfoot{\scriptsize%
  Line 1 \\ Line 2 \\ Line 3\\Line 4
}
\ofoot{}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[10-20]
\end{document}
```

Cannot post an image, I'm too new here :(

It should be obvious (even if in real life I do not use the footsepline and
footbotline) that the footer height is not properly computed or taken into
account.

And it's placed far too high on the page (that's not visible in the image
above).

Any idea on how to solve those two problems?

EDIT :
After a lots of tries and reading, I found something that gets me closer to my target (while waiting for the next release of KomaScript, as said in comment 1). My documents now start with

```
\documentclass[headheight=1.2cm,headsepline]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm,footskip=8mm]{geometry}
```

It's the `bottom` abd `footskip` parameters of `geometry` package that are relevant. The footer is properly placed (not too high) and I have no overlapping between page text and footer.

Comment: There is no official option since there is no `\footheight` in LaTeX2e so a manual solution is needed, maybe placing the footer entry in an appropriate box. [Markus Kohm plans to add corresponding options to the next release of KOMA-Script, though](http://www.komascript.de/releasesvn).

Comment: You can use "titleps". See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114548/how-to-have-headers-section-headings-and-figures-expand-into-the-margin

Answer (score 7):

Since version 3.12 KOMA-Script provides the options

- `footheight` – equivalent of the `headheight` option for the footer
- `footlines` – specify number of lines of the footer instead of the height (default is `1.25`), equivalent of the option `headlines` (provided since v3.00, default `1.25`).

If used in combination with the `scrpage2` successor `scrlayer-scrpage` which knows about `footheight` the setup would be

```
\documentclass[
  headlines=4,
  headsepline,
  footheight=38pt,
  footsepline,
  footbotline
]{scrartcl}
```

I used `footheight=38pt` because `footlines` seems to assume the base font size which is too large since you're using `\scriptsize`. I found `38pt` by using a too small value and looking in the log file at the resulting warning which one is needed...

BTW: I would specify `\scriptsize` in the `pagefoot`  KOMA-font instead of placing it in `\cfoot`:

```
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont\sffamily\scriptsize}
```

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  headlines=4,
  headsepline,
  footheight=38pt,
  footsepline,
  footbotline
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont\sffamily\scriptsize}

\ihead{}
\chead{}
\ohead{%
  Line 1 \\ Line 2 \\ Line 3\\ Line 4%
}

\ifoot{}
\cfoot{%
  Line 1 \\ Line 2 \\ Line 3\\ Line 4%
}
\ofoot{}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[10-20]
\end{document}
```