# How to get Tufte-like margins with the KOMA book class?

Tags: margins, koma-script, tufte

I asked similar question here [How to have headers, section headings, and figures expand into the margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114548/how-to-have-headers-section-headings-and-figures-expand-into-the-margin)

From [Document class for designing a book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135046/document-class-for-designing-a-book)

I want to have new insight...

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=half, DIV=calc, BCOR=10mm, x11names]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, libertine}
\usepackage{amsmath, xcolor, tcolorbox, empheq}
\usepackage[ilines, headsepline]{scrpage2}
\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}
```

gives page number in margin.

Is there any KOMA option to make the figure to use margine space. I want to center the figure using length "textwidth+marginewidth".

Can i use something similar to code below for entire document only for text and equations (Not for tables and figures)

```
\begin{addmargin}[4em]{0em}
text  
\end{addmargin}
```

Comment: Which environments should use the margin as well? Maybe I got it all wrong, but why don't you just redefine the environment »figure«, so that it includes an addmargin environment?

Comment: @keks-dose I do not know how to redefine "figure" environment with addmargine. OR can we add -ve margine like \begin{addmargin}[-4em]{0em}?

Comment: Neither do I, it is obviously not simple, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1566053 . But I strongly recommend to ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to emulate the length of Tufte's lines with Koma and I've found a pair of commands of interest.

The first one is the cited environment *addmargin* that I use with this options:

```
\begin{addmargin}[4cm]{0cm}  
\section{Section1}  
 text 
\section{Section2}   
 more text  
\end{addmargin}
```

This makes the sectioning headlines begin with the same indentation of text. But I want section numbers a little on left, with the idea that they mark the hierarchy of sectioning, so I redefine the commandement *\othersectionlevelsformat* in this way:

```
\renewcommand*{\othersectionlevelsformat}[1]{%
\makebox[0pt][r]{\csname the#1\endcsname\autodot\enskip}}
```

You can see the resulting PDF and the source tex file in my space:
https://sites.google.com/site/catalatex9/home/koma/manualreferencia

Comment: The document looks very nice. But for large number of pages, it is good to set figure margin larger (i feel).

Comment: We have new package sidenotes with figure* and table* options

Comment: See the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170248/wrong-position-of-caption-in-odd-page-with-sidenotes-in-figure