# Insert multiple sub-captions (a,b,...) aligned below flowchart figure

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I have a single figure representing the system transitioning between 5 states proceeding from left to right.  I would like to add an aligned sub-caption below each state (a), (b), etc.   Because the states are all wrapped up in a single figure this exceeds my current understanding in Latex.

This is my code printing the figure:

```
\begin{figure*}[b!] 
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figure_1.eps}
  \caption{\label{fig:static_analysis} Transition graphs.}
\end{figure*}
```

For reference, this is what the SINGLE figure and caption end state should look like:

```
--    --    --    --    --
-- -> -- -> -- -> -- -> --
--    --    --    --    --
(a)   (b)   (c)   (d)   (e)
 Fig. X: Transition states
```

Can I insert the sub-captions manually or do I need to split the figure up into individual chunks?  The former would be preferred because of some transition arrows between the states.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to place two figures next to each other and centered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254040/how-to-place-two-figures-next-to-each-other-and-centered)

Comment: As I stated, it is a single figure with multiple parts.  I would like to manually add sub-captions to break up the figure.

Comment: Sorry. By the way, there is really nothing "magical" about the `figure`s; "[inserting] the sub-captions manually" and "[splitting] the figure up into individual chunks" are not that different. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `minipage`s for subfigures, and `\caption*`s for subcaptions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{a}
        \caption*{(a)}
    \end{minipage} \hfill \(\rightarrow\) \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{b}
        \caption*{(b)}
    \end{minipage} \hfill \(\rightarrow\) \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{c}
        \caption*{(c)}
    \end{minipage} \hfill \(\rightarrow\) \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{d}
        \caption*{(d)}
    \end{minipage} \hfill \(\rightarrow\) \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{e}
        \caption*{(e)}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Transition states}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

(You can remove the dummy text introduced by `\lipsum`.)
This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: This looks like it should work.  I also just stumbled on the correct google search for my problem (duplicate question):  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211748/multiple-captions-under-a-single-figure

Comment: @Shawn Good job. Would it be appropriate to mark this question as a duplicate of that question then?

Comment: That would be fine with me.  Thanks for your assistance.