# ConTeXt: Extend figure into margin with \placefigure

Tags: context

I would like to extend a figure into the margin pretty much as done here in LaTeX: [Place figures side by side, spill into outer margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/place-figures-side-by-side-spill-into-outer-margin)

My idea was to place the figure `right` and make it wider than `\textwidth`.

`\placefigure[right]{My caption}{\externalfigure[foo.png][width=1.2\textwidth]}`

But that's not working since the figure is then extending into the right margin and not into the left :(

Comment: Have you looked in the [details](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/details.pdf) document? I think it is covered there. (I'm not able to check it right now.)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, setting the `location` parameter in `\setupfloat` does the trick.

`\setupfloat[figure][default=here,location=right]
\placefigure[]{My caption}{\externalfigure[foo.png][width=1.2\textwidth]}`